# Is WPF right for my 3D menu needs in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I want to create a menu where there is a cube, and by pressing the arrow keys, you can rotate the cube to see the different faces of the cube. On each face, there will be text. If you press enter, it will go and do whatever option you selected on the cube. I have been working on this in C# in a combination of windows forms and WPF user controls and I need to know, is it a good idea to use the integrated 3D functionality in WPF for C#, or do I need to use something else (preferably not directx or any other derivatives of it (including wrapper classes)). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Where could I post a question like this then? (thanks for the quick response)

Comment: @bdimag P.SE has the *exact same* close reason as this question was closed with.  Please check to make sure things are on topic on the target site before suggesting them (or better yet, flag it for migration instead of suggesting).  Reposting with an existing answer here makes for scattering of the material across SE which is less than desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid - you can easily do 3d stuff in WPF. The performance will be "not optimal" but basically you ask for something extremely simple - so it is definitely good enough (as in: you can not do a proper 3d game in WPF, with good quality, but a menuy is really trivial, graphically).